# Show/Hide Div Disappearing Issue. Secondary Nav Vanishes When Clicked On

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, navigation, show-hide

Good morning,
I have a Show/Hide Nav Menu which when clicked on the first item, will produce a second nav menu that is segmented from the first selection. The problem is, when I click on the next set of nav items, the item that is linked to the secondary Nav disappears, but the item appears. I don't see why the secondary Nav menu disappears...I want it to stay visible, so that end-users don't have to go back and forth.

HTML:

```
<div class="floor"><div id="content">
<div id="hide_show">
  <nav2>
    <h2>Menù </h2>
    <div id="menuSX">
      <ul><h2>Number of Bedrooms</h2>
        <li><a class="menuitem" href="#A">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="menuitem" href="#B">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="menuitem" href="#C">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav2>
      <div class="menubox" id="A">
     <nav2><div id="menuSX"><ul><h2>Floor Plan</h2><li><a class="menuitem" href="#floor1">Reed</a></li>
<li><a class="menuitem" href="#floor2">Sotol</a></li>
<li><a class="menuitem" href="#floor3">Yucca</a></li>
</ul></div></nav2>
      </div>
    <div class="menubox" id="B">
      <h2>Sotol</h2></div>
    <div class="menubox" id="C">
      <h2>Yucca</h2></div>
  </div>
 <div class="menubox"id="floor1"><a href="http://sanisidroapartmentssantafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/home-placeholder2.png"><img src="http://sanisidroapartmentssantafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/home-placeholder2.png" alt="home-placeholder2" width="175" height="195" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-122" /></a>
Make our Santa Fe apartment community your home with a variety of one-, two-, and three-bedroom floor plans to choose from. Settle into a pet-friendly luxury apartment home that suits your current lifestyle and enjoy the fact that there is also room to grow.</div> 
</div>
<div class="clear"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.floor{
max-width: 953px;
border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
padding: 15px;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.entry-content li{
 margin: 0;
}
.entry-content ul{
 list-style: none;
}
nav2 ul, nav2 ol {list-style: none; list-style-image: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
 nav2.collapsible > h2 {
background-color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menuitem {
display: block;
background-color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 0.2em;
color: #333;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    }
   .menuitem:hover  {
background-color: #AE7450;
    }
   @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  nav2 > h2 {display: none;}
  nav2 {
float: left;
width: 30%;
   }
   #hide_show {
float: left;
width: 100%;
   }
   #menuSX {
float: left;
width: 100%;
    }
   #Content3 {
float: right;
width: 69%;
    }

   .menubox{
max-width: 375px;
    }
    }
   .small-type{
    font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Average Sans', san-serif;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
 var collapsed = true;
 $('nav2>h2').click(function() {
 collapsed = !collapsed;
 formatSidebar();
 });
 $(window).resize(formatSidebar);
 formatSidebar();

 function formatSidebar() {
 if ($(window).width() > 766) {
  $('nav2').removeClass('collapsible');
  $('nav2 #menuSX').show();
 } else {
  $('nav2').addClass('collapsible');
  if (collapsed) { 
    $('nav2 #menuSX').hide();
    $('nav2 > h2').removeClass('minus');
  } else {
    $('nav2 #menuSX').show();
    $('nav2 > h2').addClass('minus');
  }
  }
  };
  });


 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menubox").hide();
  $(".menubox:first").hide();

   $(".menuitem").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".menubox").hide();
    var relatedDivID = $(this).attr('href');

    $("" + relatedDivID).fadeToggle("slow","linear"); 
    });
    });</script>
```

I have only linked up the 1st menu item on each Nav menu. If I can just get that secondary nav menu to stay put, I will be good to go. Thanks for your help. 
Here is the page: http://www.sanisidroapartmentssantafe.com/floor-plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the the items in the sub-menu "Floor Plan" have the same class(`.menuitem`) and the items in "Number of Bedrooms".

As you have it now, when the user clicks an option it hides `.menubox` which contains the "Floor Plan" lists. This is fine when you are toggling between number of bedrooms. but causes a problem when you click the options under the "Floor Plan" list. Because those options have the same class(`.menuitem`) which is set to hide `.menubox` which in this case if also the container of the the "Floor Plan" links.

One fix for this is as follows:

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h9Cv/).

Change the class associated with the options under "Floor Plan".

```
<div class="menubox" id="A">
    <nav2>
        <div id="menuSX"><ul><h2>Floor Plan</h2>
            <li><a class="sub-menuitem" href="#floor1">Reed</a></li>
            <li><a class="sub-menuitem" href="#floor2">Sotol</a></li>
            <li><a class="sub-menuitem" href="#floor3">Yucca</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav2>
</div>
```

Here I have changed each of the classes to `.sub-menuitem`.

Added this class to the css:

```
.menuitem, .sub-menuitem {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    color: #333;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.menuitem:hover, .sub-menuitem:hover  {
    background-color: #AE7450;
}
```

And finally added some javascript for `.sub-menuitem` to prevent the default action on the new class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menubox").hide();
  $(".menubox:first").hide();

   $(".menuitem").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".menubox").hide();
    var relatedDivID = $(this).attr('href');

    $("" + relatedDivID).fadeToggle("slow","linear"); 
    });

    $(".sub-menuitem").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var relatedDivID = $(this).attr('href');

    $("" + relatedDivID).fadeToggle("slow","linear"); 
    });
});
```

Doing it this way also allows you to assign some additional events to this sub-menu in the future if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The secondary nav stays put, but the #floor1 item isn't showing when I click on "Reed"

Comment: My mistake. I have edited my response above with the correct change in the javascript.

and here is an updated JSFiddle 
**[link](http://jsfiddle.net/8h9Cv/1/)**

Comment: One last question...when I added the next two items..."Sotol" and "Yucca"...how do I make the other #floors disappear and render which one was clicked? Check it out now: http://www.sanisidroapartmentssantafe.com/floor-plans

Comment: [Here is another JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8h9Cv/2/)


I changed the class of the divs holding the floor plan info and images to `menubox-floorplan` and then changed the line in the javascript that reads `$(".menubox:first").hide();` to `$(".menubox-floorplan").hide();`